# How to load all product in admin panel?

Tags: magento-1.9, product

I want to load all product in grid, here is option 20,30,40,50,100,200.
so i want to add one more load all option. can it possible?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to change `admin GRID widget` for this.

Edit `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/widget/grid.phtml` file

Find this code:

```
<select name="<?php echo $this->getVarNameLimit() ?>" onchange="<?php echo $this->getJsObjectName() ?>.loadByElement(this)">
    <option value="20"<?php if($this->getCollection()->getPageSize()==20): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>20</option>
    <option value="30"<?php if($this->getCollection()->getPageSize()==30): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>30</option>
    <option value="50"<?php if($this->getCollection()->getPageSize()==50): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>50</option>
    <option value="100"<?php if($this->getCollection()->getPageSize()==100): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>100</option>
    <option value="200"<?php if($this->getCollection()->getPageSize()==200): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>200</option>
</select>
```

This code is responsible for generating View options. You can edit it like:

```
<select name="<?php echo $this->getVarNameLimit() ?>" onchange="<?php echo $this->getJsObjectName() ?>.loadByElement(this)">
    <option value="20"<?php if($this->getCollection()->getPageSize()==20): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>20</option>
    <option value="30"<?php if($this->getCollection()->getPageSize()==30): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>30</option>
    <option value="50"<?php if($this->getCollection()->getPageSize()==50): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>50</option>
    <option value="100"<?php if($this->getCollection()->getPageSize()==100): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>100</option>
    <option value="200"<?php if($this->getCollection()->getPageSize()==200): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>200</option>
    //Adding more options
    <option value="500"<?php if($this->getCollection()->getPageSize()==500): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>500</option>
    <option value="1000"<?php if($this->getCollection()->getPageSize()==1000): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>1000</option>
    //ALL option
    <option value=""<?php if($this->getCollection()->getPageSize()==""): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>All</option>
</select>
```

This will add `500`, `1000` and `ALL` view options

**UPDATE** : Here `grid.phtml` is a core adminhtml template. You should not directly edit it.

The shortest way for this is to create a new admin theme. Edit `app/etc/local.xml` and add below code :

```
<config>
    <stores>
        <admin>
            <design>
                <theme>
                    <default>your_theme_name</default>
                </theme>
            </design>
        </admin>
    </stores>
</config>
```

Now copy `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/widget/grid.phtml` to `app/design/adminhtml/default/your_theme_name/template/widget/grid.phtml` and apply above changes to this file.

Comment: i want to load all product

Comment: check updated answer

Comment: @AjayPatel: have you tried this solution ?

Comment: yes its working but not as my requirement.

Comment: I've tested this code, Ajay and it's working. It is adding ALL option, isn't it ?

Comment: Have you any idea how to export excel from product grid??

Answer (score 3):

in app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/widget/grid.phtml

```
<select name="<?php echo $this->getVarNameLimit() ?>" onchange="<?php echo $this->getJsObjectName() ?>.loadByElement(this)">
    <option value="20"<?php if($this->getCollection()->getPageSize()==20): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>20</option>
    <option value="30"<?php if($this->getCollection()->getPageSize()==30): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>30</option>
    <option value="50"<?php if($this->getCollection()->getPageSize()==50): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>50</option>
    <option value="100"<?php if($this->getCollection()->getPageSize()==100): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>100</option>
    <option value="200"<?php if($this->getCollection()->getPageSize()==200): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>200</option>
    <option value="<?php echo $this->getCollection()->getSize(); ?>"<?php if($this->getCollection()->getPageSize()==$this->getCollection()->getSize()): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>All</option>
</select>
```

Note:- Dont add directly in file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/widget/grid.phtml . you must write this template into your theme dir. if you directly change in the core file whenever you upgrade your magento version this changes will override.

Comment: Ok this answer is quite helpful